# Cassandra Cluster with Multiple Datacenter fail Authenticaion only for a specific user

Tags: authentication, cassandra, cluster-computing

I've created a cassandra cluster as follow:

> ## Datacenter: MG
>
> Status=Up/Down
>   |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
>   --  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
>   UN  192.168.0.120  128.45 KB  256     13.3%  e1c9e29f-b6f4-4e9f-89f2-bd19153e3253  RACK01
>   UN  192.168.0.121  115.01 KB  256     12.6%  a45f35b7-dbcc-4b09-a35f-5836cabfdedb  RACK01
>
> ## Datacenter: SP
>
> Status=Up/Down
>   |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
>   --  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
>   UN  192.168.0.101  143.25 KB  256     13.1%  3b3bccf9-63bf-4a33-8efb-412efec35f3d  RACK01
>   UN  192.168.0.100  126.63 KB  256     12.4%  1123cc2f-4ae3-4045-bfe5-1395c36692de  RACK01
>   UN  192.168.0.103  151.64 KB  256     11.2%  a9baf020-a1af-4b08-825c-b0e49e938802  RACK02
>   UN  192.168.0.102  150.65 KB  256     12.3%  ce96514f-6f23-4c02-b246-86c0be717ca5  RACK02
>
> ## Datacenter: RJ
>
> Status=Up/Down
>   |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
>   --  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
>   UN  192.168.0.111  155.03 KB  256     12.9%  2157445b-d455-4e19-8394-0a9f67397f2e  RACK01
>   UN  192.168.0.110  131.14 KB  256     12.3%  9aaa5de2-37fc-4810-9563-4d711a9457e6  RACK01

For every node I've enabled PasswordAuthenticator and created a "username" with password "password" as superuser. Also I've configured the rpc_address to the node ip address.

When typing ./cqlsh -u username -p password ip_addr on any node from "SP" datacenter I can get connected. However if I try connect to any other node from "MG" or "RJ" datacenter the response is a AuthenticationException: Cannot Achieve consistency level LOCAL_ONE.

Two things are bugging me:

1. When I try to connect using username "cassandra" and password "cassandra" I can connect on any node of any datacenter
2. I doubled check and every keyspace on every node has a consistency level of ONE

Does someone has any clue on what can be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've just performed some research and found out that in despite of creating a cluster, the keyspace for "system_auth" is configured by default using SimpleStrategy; however such a strategy shall not be used when using multiple datacenters.

So I changed the system_auth keyspace by using ALTER KEYSPACE command and setting a replication of type 'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'MG':1, 'SP':2, 'RJ':1

Now I am able to connect on every node since all username/password data was replicted for all datacenters.

I'm still learning some tricks about cassandra, so excuse the lack of more deep information.

Anyway hope this can help.